# Rename a file with a "+" in its filename

Tags: macos, bash, special-characters, rename

I'm sure it's something trivial. I have a file called : "AVP + D 16.12.2013.pdf"
I need to remove the +, the points and the spaces to stay with "AVPD16122013.pdf"

I would need a bash command that is similar in OSx and Ubuntu if it's possible.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can use BASH string manipulation:

```
s="AVP + D 16.12.2013.pdf"
ext="${s##*.}"
fn="${s%.*}"
echo "${fn//[.+ ]/}.$ext"
AVPD16122013.pdf
```

Comment: I'd strip the extension off first, then restore it. Not quite every period needs to be removed :)

Comment: To rename, you can use `rename 's/[+ ]//g' "AVP + D 16.12.2013.pdf"` - also having the problem with the dot. I would maybe store the extension and then write it back.

Comment: Ok just fixed it. OP says OSX that's why rename won't be available (as it is not available for me on OSX).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this needs to be done in general for files with similar names or just for this specific file name.  If its the specific case, then the following is all you need:

```
$ mv 'AVP + D 16.12.2013.pdf' AVPD16122013.pdf
$
```

Tested on OSX 10.8.5 and Ubuntu 12.04